# Get error when Upload video file using php

Tags: php, html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                  <table align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td>Title :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="title" size="150"  value= "" /> </td>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>Choose a file to upload: </td>
                      <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
```

**My PHP:**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{


    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)//get error on here when upload video
      {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
         // echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
         // echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        /*  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
          echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
          */

          if (file_exists("pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))//get error on here when upload video
            {
               //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
          else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
             }}}
```

I can upload the pdf, image, mp3 file using this code but can't upload the video
I got a error:
"Notice: Undefined index: file in "
How can I remove this error?
Please Help......

Comment: I think you have a resource limit problem. How big is the file you want to upload? Does it exceed the limits in php.ini? Check `post_max_size`, `upload_max_size`, `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that the php script can't find the file. Good chance this is because the file you tried to upload was too big and the server rejected it. Check you php.ini file and change the `upload_max_size` property (change `post_max_size` aswell).

To check if this really is the problem you could get another mp3 file and make it as big as the video file. If uploading this file fails aswell the problem should be the size of the uploaded data.

Answer (score 0):

The video upload process is exactly the same for any type of file. Just change the extension-checking part of the code. Also, PHP has a size limit for uploads, which video files are more likely to exceed. That can be changed in php.ini.

Possible reason for your error:

file is too large and exceeds limits set in php.ini. Look for upload_max_filesize and max_post_size. By default those are just a few megs, which is probably not enough for a video file.